# Lightning Experience: Can standard Listview Charts be shared and deployed as Metadata?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, lightning-experience, metadata, list-view

I've created several Charts in Standard Listviews on Tabs in LEX. So far they work as expected and look like this:

[image]

Now logging in as an other user I've noticed that the charts are not available. Only the user who has created them seems to have access to them.

Second thing I noticed that these charts get not deployed (via ANT or eclipse). We have included the relevant Custom Object and the ListViews into the deployments. Can I use any Metadata-Components to bring these Charts from one Org to the other?

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: it looks like currently, it is not possible (release 55.0)

Explanation:
There are two metadata types representing charts:
**ListViewChart** (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_listviewchart.htm)
**ListViewChartInstance** (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_listviewchartinstance.htm)

This means that you can actually query your existing Charts and their instances (which are basically relations between ListView and Chart):

**ListViewChart example query:**

```
SELECT Id, IsDeleted, SobjectType, DeveloperName, Language, MasterLabel, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, OwnerId, ChartType, GroupingField, AggregateField, AggregateType 
FROM ListViewChart
```

**ListViewChartInstance example query:**

```
SELECT AggregateField, AggregateType, ChartType, DataQuery, DeveloperName, ExternalId, GroupingField, Id, IsDeletable, IsEditable, IsLastViewed, Label, ListViewChartId, ListViewContextId, SourceEntity 
FROM ListViewChartInstance 
WHERE SourceEntity='<YOUR-SOBJECT-NAME>' and ListViewContextID='<YOUR-LISTVIEW-ID>'
```

Unfortunately, it looks like this data could not be retrieved using MetadataAPI - I tried to retrieve them via sfdx:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ListViewChartInstance
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ListViewChart
```

and what I get is:

```
ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  The specified metadata type is unsupported: [listviewchartinstance]
ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  The specified metadata type is unsupported: [listviewchart]]
```

I also tried to insert them using AnonymousApex but I get error: "DML operation Insert not allowed on ListViewChart"

I found some idea on ideaexchange but it's not that popular:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXjqUAF/list-view-chart-deployment-to-higher-sandboxs